# How to unit test MassTransit consumer with no response

Tags: c#, unit-testing, masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to unit test my MassTransit consumer which does not send a response back. Currently my test does seem to be publishing a message, but the consumer is not being triggered, so my breakpoints are not getting hit within it at all.

The consumer is fairly straight forward, but it does have a service injected via DI.

```
public class BudgetExceededConsumer : IConsumer<IBudgetExceeded>
{
    private readonly INotificationHubService _notificationHubService;

    public BudgetExceededConsumer(INotificationHubService notificationHubService)
    {
        _notificationHubService = notificationHubService;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IBudgetExceeded> context)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = context.Message;

            await _notificationHubService.SendNotificationAsync(context.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to send push notification for exceeding budget usage", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The consumer is added to my Azure function using the following:

```
        builder.Services.AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<ConsumerNamespace>();

        });
```

And I have a relatively straightforward service that is used by other functions to send the messages:

```
    private readonly ISendEndpointProvider _sendEndpoint;

    public MessagingService(ISendEndpointProvider sendEndpoint)
    {
        _sendEndpoint = sendEndpoint;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage<T>(string queueName, object messageBody) where T : class, MessageBase
    {
        var endpoint = await _sendEndpoint.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri($"queue:{queueName}"));

        await endpoint.Send<T>(messageBody);
    }
```

I would like to write a simple test for the consumer so I could mock the service and then verify that the mocked service is being called. However I cannot get to the point of running a test and my consumer being hit by a breakpoint.
I am not setting up the service injected into the consumer anywhere in the DI. Currently it is not complaining about that which makes me think I am missing something in the setup.

```
    public async Task Budget_message_gets_consumed()
    {
        await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddMassTransitInMemoryTestHarness(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddConsumer<BudgetExceededConsumer>();
                cfg.AddConsumerTestHarness<BudgetExceededConsumer>();
            })
            .BuildServiceProvider(true);

        var harness = provider.GetRequiredService<InMemoryTestHarness>();

        await harness.Start();

        try
        {
            var bus = provider.GetRequiredService<IBus>();

            BudgetExceededMessage message = new BudgetExceededMessage
            {
                UserEmailAddress = "test@email.com",
                Budget = "£20.00",
                TotalSpend = "£23.56"
            };
            await bus.Publish(message);

            var result = await harness.Consumed.Any<IBudgetExceeded>();

            Assert.That(result, Is.True); //This is true
            
            var consumerHarness = provider.GetRequiredService<IConsumerTestHarness<BudgetExceededConsumer>>();
            var result2 = await consumerHarness.Consumed.Any<IBudgetExceeded>();
            Assert.That(result2, Is.True); //This is FALSE. 
        }
        finally
        {
            await harness.Stop();

            await provider.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
```

As you can see the second Assert is false. I think if this was true then I would be seeing the breakpoint in my consumer getting hit.

Is there part of the setup here I need to change so the second assert will get evaluated correctly? I know my setup is slightly different to the docs since I am not using the approach that gives a response.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I ran into more or less the same issue and ended up getting this to work correctly with two changes (second change optional).

**1. My consumer was using a named endpoint so I needed to configure this in the setup of the consumer in the harness**.

To check if this is your issue, you can look at the logs (note the 3rd and 5th lines).

```
08:00:18.424-D Starting bus: loopback://localhost/
08:00:18.440-D Endpoint Ready: loopback://localhost/mbp14_testhost_bus_gtwyyyrqpojbqfzhbdpgyrnng6
08:00:18.440-D Endpoint Ready: loopback://localhost/PublishPdp
08:00:18.442-I Bus started: loopback://localhost/
08:00:18.454-D Create send transport: loopback://localhost/publish-pdp?bind=true
08:00:18.507-D SEND loopback://localhost/publish-pdp?bind=true 34680000-8e6c-1217-6974-08da601042eb Ownit.Next.Common.Messages.PublishPdp
```

Notice the two different addresses: `PublishPdp` vs `publish-pdp`.  In the test harness, adding this code:

```
EndpointConvention.Map<PublishPdp>(new Uri("queue:publish-pdp"));
```

Is not sufficient, I also had to update the consumer configuration:

```
await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddConsumer<PublishPdpConsumer>()
           .Endpoint(e => e.Name = "publish-pdp"); // Explicitly set the name.
    })
    .AddScoped(x => Log.Logger)
    .BuildServiceProvider(true);
```

or use the default naming:

```
// This also works by using the default naming scheme
EndpointConvention.Map<PublishPdp>(new Uri("queue:PublishPdp"));

await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddConsumer<PublishPdpConsumer>(); // No naming needed
    })
    .AddScoped(x => Log.Logger)
    .BuildServiceProvider(true);
```

I had assumed that the static `EndpointConvention.Map<>()` would also affect the consumer, but this is not the case.  The consumer even has a static initalizer which sets this explicitly.

It seems that the test case **must** have explicit `EndpointConvention.Map<>(new Url("queue:X"))` **and** `AddConsumer<>().Endpoint(e => e.Name = "X")` when you are not using the default name.  When you are using `Send` in the test harness, you still need to use `EndpointConvention.Map<>(new Url("queue:X"))` where `X` is the name of your message type.

**2. Explicitly adding the `AddConsumerTestHarness` does not seem necessary**.

There is some confusion because the docs only show two examples and most of the examples available on the GitHub issues shows the "old" style setup.

There is an `ObsoleteAttribute` on this method:

```
Consider migrating to AddMassTransitTestHarness, which does not require this extra configuration
```

Indeed, it does not appear necessary and the test case can be written like this:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Publish_Pdp_Is_Consumed_With_DI()
{
    // This mapping is needed in the test
    EndpointConvention.Map<PublishPdp>(new Uri("queue:publish-pdp"));

    await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
        {
            // Need to explicitly name the endpoint.  Commenting out one
            // or both causes the test to fail.
            cfg.AddConsumer<PublishPdpConsumer>()
               .Endpoint(e => e.Name = "publish-pdp");
        })
        .AddScoped(x => Log.Logger)  // I inject Serilog so I need this.
        .BuildServiceProvider(true);

    var harness = provider.GetRequiredService<ITestHarness>();

    await harness.Start();

    await harness.Bus.Send<PublishPdp>(new
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        CreatedBy = "test_user"
    });

    Assert.True(await harness.Sent.Any<PublishPdp>());
    Assert.True(await harness.Consumed.Any<PublishPdp>());
}
```

OR

```
[Fact]
public async Task Publish_Pdp_Is_Consumed_With_DI()
{
    // Map the default name
    EndpointConvention.Map<PublishPdp>(new Uri("queue:PublishPdp"));

    await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
        {
            // Don't name the endpoint, but explicitly map the default
            cfg.AddConsumer<PublishPdpConsumer>();
        })
        .AddScoped(x => Log.Logger)  // I inject Serilog so I need this.
        .BuildServiceProvider(true);

    var harness = provider.GetRequiredService<ITestHarness>();

    await harness.Start();

    await harness.Bus.Send<PublishPdp>(new
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        CreatedBy = "test_user"
    });

    Assert.True(await harness.Sent.Any<PublishPdp>());
    Assert.True(await harness.Consumed.Any<PublishPdp>());
}
```

Thanks to Chris for the helpful replies.

Answer (score 0):

If your consumer has a dependency, and that dependency is not configured in the service collection, it is likely failing when creating your consumer. If you add an `ILoggerFactory` to your container with a console output, you'd see that in the unit test output.

Or use v8 of MassTransit, with the new version of the test harness that automatically includes a console logger for test output.

Comment: Chris, I'm running into the same issue where the assert for `consumerHarness.Consumed.Any<>()` is returning false.  If I test the code manually, everything works fine.  Taking your comment into account, I removed all dependencies in the constructor and body (leaving only `Console.WriteLine`) and still observing the same.  I have a static constructor on my consumer class with a `Console.WriteLine` and it simply doesn't get hit so I'm thinking the message is being sent (first assert works), but not delivered (second assert fails).